# Android: SQLite Database. Do we need to create it?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been going through some tutorials on working with sqlite databases and they all seem to create a new database, tables, etc on the first run of the application. Is this necessary? What if I already have a pre-built database sitting in the assets folder when the application is installed? Can I not simply just open the connection to said database and start using its information or is there a specific reason everyone wants to create it using sql on first launch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question comes up frequently. Try this tutorial to use an existing database on Android:
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: Great tutorial. Thanks for the link! @barmaley is right, databases not created from within the application are read only, but the link above describes how to copy that database into the system files so it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't use database file which sits in assets folder directly as SQLite database, since this file would not be usual file located in common filesystem. E.g. you can have only readonly access to it. So the only your option is to copy those database from assets folder to device's filesystem.
2. To handle database creation for the first time and accessing it there's special helper class `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). Specifically look in `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate()` - where should sit database creation (or copying from assets folder as in your case)

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite sometime since I last worked with SQLite databases (in Android) but I believe that when they write `CREATE` statements, they always do so with the `IF NOT EXISTS` condition (i.e., `CREATE (DATABASE|TABLE) IF NOT EXISTS...`).

I don't know what you'll use SQLite for but I believe they do that in Android "just to make sure". That is, if it's the user's first time to run the app, the DB/Tables *must* be created first else app goes bonkers. Otherwise, they are (probably) created already and this case will be handled by the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause and they just go ahead and create a connection with the existing DB. Win-win.

(If, for some reason, it is not the user's first time to use the app and the DB isn't there, it will just be created again. But that's obvious isn't it? ;) )

Answer (score 0):

If you just link with preexisting database it wont bind to your system. So there may be failures. Creating db at first run is the most appropriate way to work with db.

Comment: Makes sense, but in my particular situation at the moment I have a database with 3 different tables with a couple hundred rows in each. It seems like a lot of coding to add ALL that information to the database on first run. In my situation would it make more sense to manage my db in an external editor and just add it to the application as previously described or is it still important to bind the database with the app? If creating the db from scratch is the best way to do it, I will of course follow that state of mind, but I just want to make sure i'm not creating unnecessary work for myself.